# How do I get 2 similar arrays without one affecting the other

Tags: c#

I am trying to do 2 different sorting algorithms on 2 exactly similar arrays (numbers and numbers2) that are generated through the Random class. I declare my 2 arrays and fill them with Random.NextBytes.

After that I do my first algorithm on *numbers* and then my second sorts on *numbers2*.

But I notice that *numbers2* just seems to be a pointer to *numbers* because by the time I want to sort numbers2 it is already sorted.

How do I fill numbers2 with exactly the same numbers as numbers? Do I need to do it by hand with a *for* loop? Thank you!

```
class FillArray
   {

    public byte[] numbers;
    public byte[] numbers2;

        //instantiate MS Random object
        Random Generator = new Random();


        //Constructor which takes array size
        public FillArray(int amountx)
        {
          numbers = new byte[amountx]
          Generator.NextBytes(numbers);
          numbers2 = new byte[amountx];
          numbers2 = numbers;
          amount = amountx;
        }
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what we use tags for on [so].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are reference types, so if you want to clone the array you'll need to copy it via Array.Copy.

```
int[] first = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] second = new int[first.Length];
Array.Copy( first, second, first.Length );

first[0] = 10;

// prints 10
Console.WriteLine( first[0] );

// prints 1
Console.WriteLine( second[0] );
```

You can also use [Array.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw.aspx).  If you don't have a pre-existing array you can use the `Clone()` method as well to create a new one with shallow copies of all elements.

Comment: thank you, I assume using the copy method would be similar code-wise as doing it by hand with a for loop then?

Comment: @aurelietass: Yep, semantically equivalent, though Array.Copy may be faster as it is implemented in the CLR itself.

Comment: if you want to clone an array you use "Clone" not copy! :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Just depends on whether or not you have an existing array to copy it to and you don't need to allocate another (as `Clone()` would do).  There is also the `CopyTo` method.

Comment: I'm just saying that you said " if you want to clone the array"  then you should use clone :)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 numbers2 = (byte[])numbers.Clone();
```

instead of

```
 numbers2 = new byte[amountx];
 numbers2 = numbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

use Array.Copy method: [Array.Copy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5s0whfd.aspx)

```
    int[] source = new int[5];

    source[0] = 1;
    source[1] = 2;
    source[2] = 3;
    source[3] = 4;
    source[4] = 5;

    int[] target = new int[5];

    Array.Copy(source, target, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the reference for numbers to numbers2 instead of the values.  Try this:

```
public FillArray(int amountx)
{
    numbers = new byte[amountx]
    Generator.NextBytes(numbers);
    numbers2 = new byte[amountx];
    Array.Copy(numbers, numbers2, amountx);
    amount = amountx;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since arrays are reference types, you will need to create a clone of the array:

```
class FillArray
{

    public byte[] numbers;
    public byte[] numbers2;

    //instantiate MS Random object
    Random Generator = new Random();

    //Constructor which takes array size
    public FillArray(int amountx)
    {
        numbers = new byte[amountx]
        Generator.NextBytes(numbers);
        numbers2 = new byte[amountx];

        // Array Copy solution
        Array.CopyTo(numbers2, 0);

        // Or a LINQ solution
        numbers2 = numbers.ToArray();

        // Or a Clone solution
        numbers2 = (byte[])numbers.Clone();

        amount = amountx;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ed says, arrays are reference types. Your error is below:

```
public FillArray(int amountx)
{
  numbers = new byte[amountx]
  Generator.NextBytes(numbers);
  numbers2 = new byte[amountx];
  numbers2 = numbers; // this line is why the arrays are the same
  amount = amountx;
}
```

However, I have a different solution than the other 2 presented. If you include the System.Linq namespace, you can use .ToList() and .ToArray():

```
public FillArray(int amountx)
{
  numbers = new byte[amountx]
  Generator.NextBytes(numbers);
  numbers2 = numbers.ToList().ToArray();
  amount = amountx;
}
```

You will then have 2 separate copies of the array to sort independently.